# Passing values with session and adding to session one each page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to store the values entered in `textBox's` and `dropdownList's radio buttons`.... My form is a multi paged form.
Im not sure what im doing but this is what im thinking.

I have a button that clicks to the next page. I have made a class with everyfield in the DB table i want to insert too. On the button click event i want to assign the values to the `session`. Is this how I would do it?

```
protected void img_btnNext_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
Incident obj = new Incident();
obj.witnessesYes = rad_ReportYes.Checked;
obj.witnessesNo = rad_ReportNo.Checked;

// lots more objects .... to values

Session["mySession"] = obj;
Response.Redirect("~/Communicating.aspx");
}
```

so when I go to the next page do I just carry on ? adding more values to the `obj` and adding it to `session`? Im not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the object in session has all properties, you can manipulate them anyway you need to.

```
var incident = Session["MyIncident"] != null ? (Incident)Session["MyIncident"] : new Incident();
```

Comment: So when I go to the next page I can just keep adding my object to the session and submit my obj at the end to saveChanges()

Comment: You need to reload the existing Session object (if there is one), but yes, you can do this over many pages and persist when appropriate.

Comment: how do i reload the existing session

Comment: Added an example to my answer

Comment: So just keep saving Session["mySession"] = incident on the following pages

Comment: Yes. Just make sure you use the same 'Key' when retrieving or saving to Session.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , this is one of the solution , what you can do is check if the Session is having the Object , if yes then serialize it and add more content and save it back in session with the same key. If it is empty create new Object and start. The one of the issue that have with this approach is if in case you lost your session , you can not get it back (may be issue with server etc..). In case you have more steps its better to save it in the persistence place like DB after certain steps.

```
if(Session[keyName] != NULL)
{
Incident existingValue = (Incident)Session[KeyName]
existingValue.XXXX = 10;
Session[KeyName] = existingValue ;
}
else
{
 Incident existingValue = new Incident()
 existingValue.XXXX = 10;
 Session[KeyName] = existingValue ;
}
```

Comment: What has serialization got to do with storing an object in Session?

Comment: How can you store any object in Session without serialization , generally .NET framework does for us , but it need to be done. I have updated my code above . May I know why I have -1

Comment: @ChrisBint  my solution is also same as yours which is right , I do not know then why mine is -1 :)

Comment: Well, there are various errors in the code for starters, but as said, I have no idea why it was marked down.